# How to mock a class created in constructor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-jdbc

Imagine I have a bean `JdbcTemplate`, and in only once class I need `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` explicit. It is created inside the constructor.

Question: how can I mock it during `junit` tests?

```
@Service
public class QueryService {
    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbc;

    public BookingExportService(JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        this.namedJdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
    }

    public void sql() {
        namedJdbc.query(sql1, mapSqlParameterSource, resultSetExtractor);
        namedJdbc.query(sql2, mapSqlParameterSource, resultSetExtractor);
    } 
}
```

Defining the mock is difficult here, as I have to mock the underlying `JdbcTemplate` calls. This could work as follows:

```
@MockBean
private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

@Test
public void testQuery() {
    when(jdbc.query(any(PreparedStatementCreator.class), any(ResultSetExtractor.class))).thenReturn(..);
}
```

BUT: if I have different sql queries that should produce different results (like above sql1 and sql2), then I'm out of luck and cannot differ the sql during the mock.

What are my chances?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you aren't autowiring it? You could add a (protected) setter for your template

Comment: Hm, I only need the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` inside that service, nowhere else. So would it be better I'd create the template as a `@Bean` directly application wide?

Comment: You might only need it once for functionality purpose, but as you noticed, you still have to be able to set a mock/... for testing purposes. Just because you only need it once now, doesn't mean you won't need it more later on.
Right now, you are having a hardcoded instantiation. Having it autowired will also make sure you won't have to change this class if you want to use the other constructor

Comment: Spring Boot already creates a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` out-of-the-box. S you are actually creating another one in your code. Just inject the pre-confogured one.

Comment: I've not been aware of this, ty!

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
this.namedJdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
```

That simply makes your code **hard to test**. Basically you are bypassing dependency injection here, and well, that means: you don't have any control over that field content.

Three options:

- turn to a mocking framework like PowerMock(ito) or JMockit that allow you to control calls to `new()` (not recommended)
- change your code, for example using constructor telescoping ... so that you can simply **pass** in an instance of that class (which can then be mocked with "normal" frameworks like Mockito easily)
- as you are already using a framework that has its own ideas of dependency injection (@Autowired for example): step back and do things like that framework implies it to be done.